# Inserting elements in the search URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an API call(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${e.target.value}`), what I want to do with this is to find multiple elements based on that e.target.value.
I have the following setup:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { useGlobalContext } from './helpers/context'

export default function IngredientPage() {
  var {cocktails} = useGlobalContext()
  const {ingredients} = useGlobalContext()
  const [cocktailList, setCocktailList] = useState([])
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleDropdownChange = async (e) => {
    // const ingredientURL = fetch(`www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${e.target.value}`)
    // const selectedIngredientData = ingredientURL.json()
    // console.log(selectedIngredientData)
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${e.target.value}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    const {drinks} = data
    setCocktailList(drinks)
  }

  if(cocktails.length < 1) {
    return <h2 className="section-title">No cocktails available</h2>
  }
    return (
        <div>
          <div className="form-group">
          <label>Select Ingredients</label>
          <select className="form-control" onChange={handleDropdownChange}>
          {
            ingredients.map((item) => {
                return <option key={item.ingredient} value={item.ingredient}>{item.ingredient}</option>
            })
          }
          </select>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
             <i className="fas fa-search"></i>
          </button>
          </div>
          {
            cocktailList.map((cocktail) => {
              return (
                <div key={cocktail.idDrink} className="col-sm">
                  <div className="card" style={{width: "18rem",marginTop: "2rem"}}>
                  <img className="card-img-top" src={cocktail.strDrinkThumb} alt="name" />
                  <div className="card-body">
                   <h5 className="card-title">{cocktail.strDrink}</h5>
                  </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want to find a way so I can select multiple elements or maybe when I press the button, it will add the elements in a list and implement another button for searching. Until now I can only search based on one item. Any ideas how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that [API](https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php) takes a comma separated list of ingredients.

- Search by ingredient

  ```
  www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=Gin
  www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=Vodka
  ```
- Filter by multi-ingredient (only available to $2+ Patreon supporters)

  ```
  www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=Dry_Vermouth,Gin,Anis
  ```

Assuming you've correct access, you can specify the `select` element to select multiple options using the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-multiple) attribute. This will require updating the `onChange` handler logic to iterate the selected options. Create an array of selected options and join them with `","` for the queryString value.

```
const handleDropdownChange = async (e) => {
  const { options } = e.target;
  const selected = [];
  for (const option of options) {
    if (option.selected) selected.push(option.value);
  }

  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=${selected.join(",")}`);
    const { drinks } = await response.json();
    setCocktailList(drinks);
  } catch(error) {
    // handle any errors
  }
}
```

...

```
<select
  multiple
  className="form-control"
  onChange={handleDropdownChange}
>
  {ingredients.map((item) => (
    <option key={item.ingredient} value={item.ingredient}>
      {item.ingredient}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer it really helped, but it looks that when i console.log the options I still get one drink in there. Also, I think it is impossible to make it work with the regular call?

Comment: @Razmi Hmm, I did test this out in a codesandbox and found I could log all the selected options. Are you logging the `selected` array that is populated, or something else? The "regular" API call looks to be the same endpoint, only the value passed on the `i` queryString parameter is different.

Comment: I managed to select multiple elements by pressing ctrl + click, I think is k like that too. About the "regular API", I meant if I could use this call: "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?i=Gin". Because I'm not allowed to use the payed one. Is there any way to use the regular method to return the cocktails based on multiple selected items? You really helped me a lot already and I thank you for that.

Comment: @Razmi No, I don't think so... I tried as well and still only got results for the first value of the list.